# I need assistance regarding my function and game

Tags: python, function, pygame

```
def death_en():
    death = pygame.Surface.blit(pygame.image.load('tombstone.png'))
    if x + (WarriorSize_x * .8) == x_en:
        screenDisplay.blit(death, (x_en, y_en))
```

I'm new to Python and over all programing. I have started learning about pygame and I'm trying to create a game. What I want this function to do is to put another image on top of the enemy that was killed, though nothing happens when I get close enough to it with the main character. I now I haven't assigned a y-axis, but want to make sure this works first. I could send the whole code if it's necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) You should probably include the whole code. 2) You perform the check in the function? shouldnt this be an observable callback? 3) Your tombstone will only be displayed IFF the character is at the exact position of x_en. Perhaps making a window would be better.

Answer (score 0):

To check for collisions use the [PyGame Rect Class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).  Keep a rectangle for your player, and a rectangle for each enemy, updating the position of the rect whenever the item it tracks changes position. Also, when an enemy or the player moves, use the [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) `Rect.colliderect()` to determine if the two items have intersected on-screen.

This might be something like:

```
tombstone_image = pygame.image.load('tombstone.png')

...

# Inside main loop

# Have there been any collisions?
for e_rect in all_enemy_rects:
    if ( e_rect.colliderect( player_rect ) ):
        screenDisplay.blit( tombstone_image, e_rect )
        # TODO: remove enemy from game
```